# MS Word Table with automatic computaion

Tags: excel, ms-word

I am trying to set a table with formula at the bottom that gets the Sum of the cells above. I tried to put a formula for the cells at the bottom and it works fine. The problem is that it is not automatically updated when ever data has been changed(You need to press F9).

Another problem is that formula added to cell might be deleted by pressing backspace.

I tried to copy cells for MS Excel(Because MS Excel has Autoupdate feature in its formula), but it doesn't work when pasted in MS Word.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Like creating Macro, or different way of copying cells from MS Excel etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In **MS Word**, the "Automatic" is not the same as in **MS Excel**. In **MS Excel** if you change the values, the cells with the formula is automatically updated. The same is not true in **MS Word**. You have to select the field and press <kbd>F9</kbd>

I would recommend going through this link

**Topic**: Calculate totals and other values in a Word table

**Link**: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/calculate-totals-and-other-values-in-a-word-table-HP005256736.aspx

**Quote From Above Link**

> Note: Word inserts the result of the calculation as a field in the cell you selected. If you change the values in the referenced cells, you can update the calculation by selecting the field and then pressing F9.
>
> Note: Microsoft Word table calculations must be manually recalculated. Consider using Microsoft Excel to perform complex calculations.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I am aware of the difference between the use of MS Word and MS Excel, and the fact that calculations in MS Word is not Automatic. I am asking for a way to do the "Automatic Calculation" trick. And I also need to do these in MS Word

Comment: That's what I was referring to... that you cannot. You have to do it manually by pressing F9.

Answer (score 1):

You know that there is a way to get an excel spreadsheet object to automatically re-calculate all cells when any cell is changed. In Word 2013 when you double-click on the inserted excel object it will open the spreadsheet. From the "Formulas" menu simply select "Calculation options" and then "Automatic"

Answer (score 0):

MS Word is just for word processing. You better use excel for this kind of work. 
You can keep a table with the formula in the excel. And whenever you want to change something, change it in excel file and copy-paste again into the word file.
I think it is the most convenient way.

Wish you best luck....!

Answer (score -1):

Every time I insert a new row in a Word table I can update the totals in the last row, but not the general total like =B62-C62-D62 (which are totals of these columns).
I had 12 of these tables (one per month).

I created a macro to solve this problem:

```
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer, A As String

For Y = 1 To ActiveDocument.Tables.Count 'Walk through all tables
  X = ActiveDocument.Tables(Y).Rows.Count 'Get row number of last row
  A = Mid$(Str(X), 2) 'trim preceding space
  ActiveDocument.Tables(Y).Cell(X, 1).Formula Formula:="=B" & A & "-C" & A & "-D" & A
Next

ActiveDocument.Fields.Update 'Refresh totals 1st round
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update 'Refresh totals 2nd round
```

And then put the macro as button in the quick access toolbar.

Works for me!

Comment: The only line of code in your answer that is relevant to the problem this thread discusses is ActiveDocument.Fields.Update but even that doesn't address the issue of making the calculations happen dynamically...

Comment: Adding a second ActiveDocument.Fields.Update doesn't make your code any more relevant to the problem this thread discusses than before...